# Masonry Infinite Scroll with Database and Anchor Tag that links to the current document

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am new to PHP, Javascript and HTML. So maybe I'm missing something obvious but, I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. I am trying to use Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll with a PHP file that has an anchor point that links back to itself with different GET values. The problem is that Anything I do gives me this error:

> **Sorry, we couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL. Verify your the css selector points to the correct A tag.**

I am at my wits end and desperately need someones help because I need this done by January 20th. It's going to be a birthday gift for someone I know.

Here is my code:

**index.php (Code Snippet)**

```
<div id="content-container" class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;overflow:hidden;">     
    <div class="row-fluid full">
        <div class="span12 full" style="overflow:scroll;position:relative;">
            <div id="media-palette">
                <?php       
                    include('content.php');         
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script.js (Code Snippet)**

```
$("#media-palette").infinitescroll({
    navSelector:"#next",
    nextSelector:"#media-palette a#next:last",
    itemSelector:".media-content",
    bufferPx:50,
    debug: true,
}, function(newElements) {
    $("#media-palette").masonry('append', newElements,true);
});
```

**content.php**

(It is worth noting that the images found in this file are for testing purposes and the final PHP file will load images from a database.)

```
<?php

    require('dbconnect.php');

    $startIndex = $_GET['start'];
    $endIndex = $_GET['end'];

    $nextStartIndex = $endIndex-1;
    $nextEndIndex = $endIndex-10;
?>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>    

<body>
    <?php
    $files = scandir("images");
        if ($files) {
            $length = count($files);
            static $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $extension = end(explode(".", $files[$i]));
                $extension = strtolower($extension);
                if (in_array($extension,$allowedExts)) {
                    $rand = rand(0,10);
                    if (!$rand) echo "<img class='media-content medium' src='images/".$files[$i]."'/>";
                    else echo "<img class='media-content small' src='images/".$files[$i]."'/>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<a id="next" href="content.php?start='.$nextStartIndex.'&end='.$nextEndIndex.'"></a>';
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I figured out how I can implement this. However I do not have the time to post an answer until after the site goes live. So if there is no answer and it is after January 22nd, I must have forgotten to do so. So please comment on my post to remind me.

Comment: how you figured out? :)